# AngularJs. $http post not posting all the items to a collection in a for loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, post

I have a collection to which I need to post several items in a for loop. Here is code for that:

```
            for(i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
                var request = $http({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "/students",
                    data: {
                        studentName: "Student",
                        answerImage: "image", 
                        questionPrompt: 1
                    }
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
              }
```

When I search the collection, it only posted 23 items. I have cleared my collection and tried this several times and each time it posts only 20-23 items. All the fields for the data are fine. This is the error response I get on the console:

```
 Object {data: null, status: -1, config: Object, statusText: ""}
```

I am not sure what to do from here. In my real app, I would need to post something like ~200 items to this collection in this for loop. Is it a timing out issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible you might be running into a timeout here because the browser is going to rate limit how many concurrent requests you can make to the same domain. **Typically that number is 6, but differs depending on the browser.**

In general, making 200+ HTTP requests at once is going to be a real drag on your application.

A better approach would be to either modify your endpoint to take a collection, or create a new endpoint that does. A single request with 200 objects is going to be much more performant than trying to make 200 individual requests.