# AngularJs. Using $q.all for sending multiple post requests

Tags: angularjs, post, promise, angular-promise

I have an AngularJs app in which I need to make $http post calls in a loop. Here is my code:

```
          var promisesArray = [];
          for(i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
                 promisesArray.push($http({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "/studentanswers",
                    data: {
                        studentName: "abc",
                        answerImage: "sdf",
                        questionPrompt: 1
                    }
                }));
          }
          $q.all(promisesArray).then(function(data){
              console.log("success!!!!");
          });
```

For some reason, it is not posting all the items in the collection. I am aware that browsers usually do not allow more than 6 async post calls. From what I understood, $q.all was a way around it. Also, even if I comment out the $q.all part, it doesn't matter because the post calls get executed nonetheless.

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: What does the network tab in your developer tools look like?

Comment: I printed out the error response. This is what I get about 10 or 11 times:

Object {data: null, status: -1, config: Object, statusText: ""}

Comment: Also, I asked this question before which led me to $q.all:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949265/angularjs-http-post-not-posting-all-the-items-to-a-collection-in-a-for-loop/33949308#33949308

Comment: The error message doesn't help me. Can you open your network tab in your developer tools to show which requests are being sent? You need to make sure you're trying to hit the correct routes. In this question, I don't think `$q.all` has anything to do with your problem (i.e., your code looks fine).

Comment: It looks like you may not have tested the solution that you accepted in your original question before posting another question. I would agree with this part of the accepted answerer's response: "A better approach would be to either modify your endpoint to take a collection, or create a new endpoint that does". `$q.all` is simply an implementation detail, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be aware that `$q.all` is **not resilient**. It will terminate with the first rejected promise. But that really isn't your problem.

You need to **chain** your posts to avoid the browser limit of simultaneous posts.

```
var promisesList = [];
var promiseMinusOne = $q.when();

for (var i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
    //begin IIFE closure
    function(i) {
        //chain off promiseMinusOne
        var httpPromise = 
             promiseMinusOne.catch (function (e) {
                 return e;
             }) .then (function (r) {
                 return $http({ method: "post",
                                url: "/studentanswers",
                                data: answerList[i]
                 })
             });
        promisesList.push(httpPromise);
        promiseMinusOne = httpPromise; 
    }(i);
    //end IIFE closure
};

var chainablePromise = 
    promiseMinusOne.catch (function (e) {
        return (e);
    }) .then (function (r) {
        //process the promisesList
    });
```

Notice, that for `promiseMinusOne`, the use of `.catch` and `return` in order to continue the list in the event of a rejection of one of the items.

Comment: I am very sorry for this late response. I recently got back on this project. That was it! Now it is working great. Thanks so much for your help!